# PHP regex delimiters, / vs. | vs. {} , what are the differences?

Tags: php, regex

In the PHP manual of PCRE, http://us.php.net/manual/en/pcre.examples.php, it gives 4 examples of valid patterns:

- `/<\/\w+>/`
- `|(\d{3})-\d+|Sm`
- `/^(?i)php[34]/`
- `{^\s+(\s+)?$}`

Seems that `/` , `|` or a pair of curly braces can use as delimiters, so is there any difference between them?

Comment: I'm surprised [] and {} work as starting/ending delimiters. I thought the starting delimiter had to be the same as the ending one. But yes, you can use pretty much anything you want. I often use `%` as a delimiter, as I rarely use `%` as an actual character in my patterns.

Comment: The use of "bracket-like" delimiters in matching pairs is, like the delimiter concept itself, consistent with Perl's regex literals (and probably awk etc before that).

Comment: I found this page to have a *great* explanation: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No difference, except the closing delimiter cannot appear without escaping.

This is useful when the standard delimiter is used a lot, e.g. instead of

```
preg_match("/^http:\\/\\/.+/", $str);
```

you can write

```
preg_match("[^http://.+]", $str);
```

to avoid needing to escape the `/`.

Comment: @KennyTM - The manual does not mention the use of [], but it is valid, right?

Comment: Oh, I know the answer now. "A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character." -- http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: I don't think [^http://.+] would work because it would mistakenly match any character that is not one of h,t,p , etc.  #^http://.+# or ~^http://.+~ would be fine though.

Comment: @Kenny: that's a terrible, terrible example!

Comment: Yes, seems that delimiters can be omitted if there is not modifiers. Kenny, can you edit your answer?

Comment: @powerboy the manual **does** mention the use of `[…]` as delimiters: *In addition to the aforementioned delimiters, it is also possible to use bracket style delimiters where the opening and closing brackets are the starting and ending delimiter, respectively.* [source](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters)

Comment: Note that brackets can still be used in the normal way despite being used as regex delimiters: `preg_replace("[[fo]]", "x", "foo")` yields `xxx`.  It's only "stray" closing brackets that have to be escaped.  This is another feature that's copied from Perl.

Answer (score 6):

In fact you can use any non alphanumeric delimiter (excluding whitespaces and backslashes)

```
"%^[a-z]%"
```

works as well as

```
"*^[a-z]*"
```

as well as

```
"!^[a-z]!"
```

Comment: Whitespace characters, and backslash, are non-alphanumeric, however they aren't allowed as the delimiter.