# @ in PHP regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, validation

I found this script for password validation, but I don't know, why is "@" inside patterns. Can you explain me it? Thanks

```
                $uppercase = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $_POST['password']);
            $lowercase = preg_match('@[a-z]@', $_POST['password']);
            $number = preg_match('@[0-9]@', $_POST['password']);

            if (!$uppercase || !$lowercase || !$number || strlen($_POST['password']) < 8)
            {
                $message .= "Password must contains lowercase letter, uppercase letter, digit and minimal length is 8 characters. <br/>";
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892749/php-regex-delimiters-vs-vs-what-are-the-differences

Comment: I don't agree with it, but they are using the `@` for delimiters instead of `/` for example

Comment: @, /, -, %, ` these are all delimiters. which represents the start and end of regex expression.

Comment: Technically you can use anything that is not alpha numeric can be a delimiter, including things that have meaning in regex, such as `.` or `+` or `|` etc. [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6de20c2f70e3b7c2a4b30a08630473899ccf164a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many regex libraries, the "delimiter" is actually [completely up to the programmer](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), and totally arbitrary. Basically, whatever the first char in the pattern is, that's the delimiter and when it shows up again (unescaped) the pattern is considered complete (optionally with some flags following the closing delimiter).

You can consider it a matter of programmer style/taste, or maybe they got in the habit on a project where the patterns needed `/` in the pattern and they didn't want to escape them all the time.